# Strategies for Connecting with Security and Privacy Researchers in Less Studied Regions, Especially the Middle East

Tags: research-process, international, privacy

I understand that establishing connections in various parts of the world, especially those based in less studied or underrepresented regions, such as the Middle East, might present unique challenges due to differences in academic networks, cultural contexts, and possibly limited visibility of local researchers on international platforms. Therefore, I seek advice and strategies to effectively connect with security and privacy researchers in these areas.

What are the most effective platforms or networks to discover and connect with researchers from less studied regions, particularly the Middle East?

Comment: The words privacy and security are used with several different meanings. Do you mean [information security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security) and [information privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_privacy)? (If you were referring to other types of security like [national security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_security), then that's a context for which surely the Middle East is one of the most studied regions instead of least studied...)

Comment: I mean the intersection of Security-Privacy with HCI. @DanRomik

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two possibilities.

First, identify some top universities that have a technical focus, though the overall mission might be broader. Write to department heads there in CS and IT departments (or look at web sites) to see if you can be put in contact with individuals.

Second, look to professional societies that have a focus on your area of interest. Both ACM and IEEE come to mind, but there are others. They may publish directories of members.

Not quite so obvious is to look at who has presented papers at conferences in the field and look at their affiliations. The professional societies that sponsor these have web pages for the conference and they seem to be maintained year after year.